Getting error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'isCE') with rollup
I migrated my vue app from v2 to v3 and now when I use a component with slots then it gives error,
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'isCE')

But if I remove slots then it works.
This is my rollup.config.js file that has the config for loading the vue app.
I tried different configuration but didnt work.
 import vue from "rollup-plugin-vue"; // Handle .vue files
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve"; // Teach Rollup how to find external modules
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs"; // Convert CommonJS modules to ES6
  import image from "@rollup/plugin-image";
import copy from "rollup-plugin-copy";
import pjson from "./package.json" assert { type: "json" };
 import scss from "rollup-plugin-scss";
 import url from "@rollup/plugin-url";

export default {
  external: ["vue"],
  input: "src/index.js", // Entry point for your app
  output: {
    format: "esm",
    file: "dist/library.js",
    exports: "auto",  
  },

  plugins: [
    resolve({
      browser: true, // Browser target (if necessary)
      dedupe: ["vue"], // Avoid duplicated packages
    }),

    scss({
      prefix: `@use 'sass:math'; @import "./src/css/index.scss";`,
    }),
    vue({
      template: {
        isProduction: true,
      },
    }),

    commonjs(),
    copy({
      targets: [
        { src: "src/css/index.scss", dest: "dist/" }, 
        { src: "src/img/*", dest: "img/" },
      
        {
          src: "src/config/lang/*",
          dest: "dist/lang",
          rename: (name, extension, fullPath) => `global_${name}.${extension}`,
        },
      ],
    }),
    image(), // Optional: Minify JavaScript
    url({
      // by default, rollup-plugin-url will not handle font files
      include: [
        "**/*.svg",
        "**/*.png",
        "**/*.jpg",
      
      ],
      publicPath: "/public",
    }),
  ],
};


Slots as in this? https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/slots-unification.html

No if I put slots in child component like   and then starts to give error when I use that component no matter if use the slots in parent component or not
